# Simple API Calls with Node.js and Express

Tags: node.js, express

I'm just getting started with Node, APIs, and web applications.

I understand the basic workings of Node.js and Express, but now I want to start making calls to other service's APIs and to do stuff with their data.

Can you outline basic HTTP requests and how to grab/parse the responses in Node? I'm also interested in adding specific headers to my request (initially I'm using the http://www.getharvest.com API to crunch my timesheet data).

P.S. This seems simple, but a lot of searching didn't turn up anything that answered my question. If this is dupe, let me know and I'll delete.

Comment: What version of Node.js are you using?

Comment: Node version is currently 0.4.12.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You cannot fetch stuff with Express, you should use Mikeal's [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) library for that specific purpose.

**Installation:** `npm install request`

The API for that library is very simple:

```
const request = require('request');
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Print the google web page.
  }
})
```

Edit: You're better of using this library instead of the http default one because it has a much nicer API and some more advanced features (it even supports cookies).

**UPDATE**: request has been deprecated, but there are some nice alternatives still such as '***got***' or '***superagent***' (look them up on npm).

Comment: can you please tell me, that is it necessary to end the request, like we will be using '.end()' for the http request?

Comment: I think that's only required for the native http client. `request` does that for you and exposes a friendlier interface.

Comment: Anyone coming across this, the 'request' library is deprecated.

Comment: Keep in mind that this library is already depracated (since Feb 2020).

Comment: request is now deprecated.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Answer (score 7):

You can use the http client:

```
var http = require('http');
var client = http.createClient(3000, 'localhost');
var request = client.request('PUT', '/users/1');
request.write("stuff");
request.end();
request.on("response", function (response) {
  // handle the response
});
```

Also, you can set headers as described in the [api documentation](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.3.1/api/http.html#http.Client):

```
client.request(method='GET', path, [request_headers])
```

Comment: In case anyone else comes across this, this method is deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

> Required install two package.

```
npm install ejs 
npm install request
```

> server.js

```
var request = require('request');
app.get('/users', function(req, res) {
    request('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users', function(error, response, body) {
        res.json(body)
    });
});
```

> index.ejs

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:3000/posts',
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(res) {
        var res_data = JSON.parse(res);
        console.log(res_data);
    }
});
```

> Output

[image]